# PHPSpreadsheet - How do I create a zip file from PHPSpreadsheet?

Tags: database, save, zip, file-writing, phpspreadsheet

I'm currently trying to pull data from a database, to which it's then written to two separate sheets using PHPSpreadsheet. The problem that I have is that I can't download multiple files, and can't find a way to zip them.

How would I be able to save these spreadsheets into a file and load it into a ZIP? Below shows how it is written to a file:

```php
    function saveToFile($spreadsheet, $job_id) {
        $filename = $job_id.'_space_validation-'.'.xlsx';
        // Redirect output to a client's web browser (Xlsx)
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
         
        // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
        header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
        header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
        header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
        header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.

        writeToFile($spreadsheet);
    }

    function writeToFile($spreadsheet) {

        $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
        $writer->save('php://output');
    }
```

**EDIT**: I've been looking through the code for the function 'save'. This code is a little advanced for me but from what I can see it creates a temporary file and writes all the data to it. I don't know how, but I figure that if I can get this temp file I might be able to send it to a zip file. Here's the code below for this function:

```php
    public function save($pFilename)
    {
        if ($this->spreadSheet !== null) {
            // garbage collect
            $this->spreadSheet->garbageCollect();

            // If $pFilename is php://output or php://stdout, make it a temporary file...
            $originalFilename = $pFilename;
            if (strtolower($pFilename) == 'php://output' || strtolower($pFilename) == 'php://stdout') {
                $pFilename = @tempnam(File::sysGetTempDir(), 'phpxltmp');
                if ($pFilename == '') {
                    $pFilename = $originalFilename;
                }
            }

            $saveDebugLog = Calculation::getInstance($this->spreadSheet)->getDebugLog()->getWriteDebugLog();
            Calculation::getInstance($this->spreadSheet)->getDebugLog()->setWriteDebugLog(false);
            $saveDateReturnType = Functions::getReturnDateType();
            Functions::setReturnDateType(Functions::RETURNDATE_EXCEL);

            // Create string lookup table
            $this->stringTable = [];
            for ($i = 0; $i < $this->spreadSheet->getSheetCount(); ++$i) {
                $this->stringTable = $this->getWriterPart('StringTable')->createStringTable($this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i), $this->stringTable);
            }

            // Create styles dictionaries
            $this->styleHashTable->addFromSource($this->getWriterPart('Style')->allStyles($this->spreadSheet));
            $this->stylesConditionalHashTable->addFromSource($this->getWriterPart('Style')->allConditionalStyles($this->spreadSheet));
            $this->fillHashTable->addFromSource($this->getWriterPart('Style')->allFills($this->spreadSheet));
            $this->fontHashTable->addFromSource($this->getWriterPart('Style')->allFonts($this->spreadSheet));
            $this->bordersHashTable->addFromSource($this->getWriterPart('Style')->allBorders($this->spreadSheet));
            $this->numFmtHashTable->addFromSource($this->getWriterPart('Style')->allNumberFormats($this->spreadSheet));

            // Create drawing dictionary
            $this->drawingHashTable->addFromSource($this->getWriterPart('Drawing')->allDrawings($this->spreadSheet));

            $zip = new ZipArchive();

            if (file_exists($pFilename)) {
                unlink($pFilename);
            }
            // Try opening the ZIP file
            if ($zip->open($pFilename, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) !== true) {
                if ($zip->open($pFilename, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== true) {
                    throw new WriterException('Could not open ' . $pFilename . ' for writing.');
                }
            }

            // Add [Content_Types].xml to ZIP file
            $zip->addFromString('[Content_Types].xml', $this->getWriterPart('ContentTypes')->writeContentTypes($this->spreadSheet, $this->includeCharts));

            //if hasMacros, add the vbaProject.bin file, Certificate file(if exists)
            if ($this->spreadSheet->hasMacros()) {
                $macrosCode = $this->spreadSheet->getMacrosCode();
                if ($macrosCode !== null) {
                    // we have the code ?
                    $zip->addFromString('xl/vbaProject.bin', $macrosCode); //always in 'xl', always named vbaProject.bin
                    if ($this->spreadSheet->hasMacrosCertificate()) {
                        //signed macros ?
                        // Yes : add the certificate file and the related rels file
                        $zip->addFromString('xl/vbaProjectSignature.bin', $this->spreadSheet->getMacrosCertificate());
                        $zip->addFromString('xl/_rels/vbaProject.bin.rels', $this->getWriterPart('RelsVBA')->writeVBARelationships($this->spreadSheet));
                    }
                }
            }
            //a custom UI in this workbook ? add it ("base" xml and additional objects (pictures) and rels)
            if ($this->spreadSheet->hasRibbon()) {
                $tmpRibbonTarget = $this->spreadSheet->getRibbonXMLData('target');
                $zip->addFromString($tmpRibbonTarget, $this->spreadSheet->getRibbonXMLData('data'));
                if ($this->spreadSheet->hasRibbonBinObjects()) {
                    $tmpRootPath = dirname($tmpRibbonTarget) . '/';
                    $ribbonBinObjects = $this->spreadSheet->getRibbonBinObjects('data'); //the files to write
                    foreach ($ribbonBinObjects as $aPath => $aContent) {
                        $zip->addFromString($tmpRootPath . $aPath, $aContent);
                    }
                    //the rels for files
                    $zip->addFromString($tmpRootPath . '_rels/' . basename($tmpRibbonTarget) . '.rels', $this->getWriterPart('RelsRibbonObjects')->writeRibbonRelationships($this->spreadSheet));
                }
            }

            // Add relationships to ZIP file
            $zip->addFromString('_rels/.rels', $this->getWriterPart('Rels')->writeRelationships($this->spreadSheet));
            $zip->addFromString('xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels', $this->getWriterPart('Rels')->writeWorkbookRelationships($this->spreadSheet));

            // Add document properties to ZIP file
            $zip->addFromString('docProps/app.xml', $this->getWriterPart('DocProps')->writeDocPropsApp($this->spreadSheet));
            $zip->addFromString('docProps/core.xml', $this->getWriterPart('DocProps')->writeDocPropsCore($this->spreadSheet));
            $customPropertiesPart = $this->getWriterPart('DocProps')->writeDocPropsCustom($this->spreadSheet);
            if ($customPropertiesPart !== null) {
                $zip->addFromString('docProps/custom.xml', $customPropertiesPart);
            }

            // Add theme to ZIP file
            $zip->addFromString('xl/theme/theme1.xml', $this->getWriterPart('Theme')->writeTheme($this->spreadSheet));

            // Add string table to ZIP file
            $zip->addFromString('xl/sharedStrings.xml', $this->getWriterPart('StringTable')->writeStringTable($this->stringTable));

            // Add styles to ZIP file
            $zip->addFromString('xl/styles.xml', $this->getWriterPart('Style')->writeStyles($this->spreadSheet));

            // Add workbook to ZIP file
            $zip->addFromString('xl/workbook.xml', $this->getWriterPart('Workbook')->writeWorkbook($this->spreadSheet, $this->preCalculateFormulas));

            $chartCount = 0;
            // Add worksheets
            for ($i = 0; $i < $this->spreadSheet->getSheetCount(); ++$i) {
                $zip->addFromString('xl/worksheets/sheet' . ($i + 1) . '.xml', $this->getWriterPart('Worksheet')->writeWorksheet($this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i), $this->stringTable, $this->includeCharts));
                if ($this->includeCharts) {
                    $charts = $this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i)->getChartCollection();
                    if (count($charts) > 0) {
                        foreach ($charts as $chart) {
                            $zip->addFromString('xl/charts/chart' . ($chartCount + 1) . '.xml', $this->getWriterPart('Chart')->writeChart($chart, $this->preCalculateFormulas));
                            ++$chartCount;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            $chartRef1 = 0;
            // Add worksheet relationships (drawings, ...)
            for ($i = 0; $i < $this->spreadSheet->getSheetCount(); ++$i) {
                // Add relationships
                $zip->addFromString('xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet' . ($i + 1) . '.xml.rels', $this->getWriterPart('Rels')->writeWorksheetRelationships($this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i), ($i + 1), $this->includeCharts));

                // Add unparsedLoadedData
                $sheetCodeName = $this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i)->getCodeName();
                $unparsedLoadedData = $this->spreadSheet->getUnparsedLoadedData();
                if (isset($unparsedLoadedData['sheets'][$sheetCodeName]['ctrlProps'])) {
                    foreach ($unparsedLoadedData['sheets'][$sheetCodeName]['ctrlProps'] as $ctrlProp) {
                        $zip->addFromString($ctrlProp['filePath'], $ctrlProp['content']);
                    }
                }
                if (isset($unparsedLoadedData['sheets'][$sheetCodeName]['printerSettings'])) {
                    foreach ($unparsedLoadedData['sheets'][$sheetCodeName]['printerSettings'] as $ctrlProp) {
                        $zip->addFromString($ctrlProp['filePath'], $ctrlProp['content']);
                    }
                }

                $drawings = $this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i)->getDrawingCollection();
                $drawingCount = count($drawings);
                if ($this->includeCharts) {
                    $chartCount = $this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i)->getChartCount();
                }

                // Add drawing and image relationship parts
                if (($drawingCount > 0) || ($chartCount > 0)) {
                    // Drawing relationships
                    $zip->addFromString('xl/drawings/_rels/drawing' . ($i + 1) . '.xml.rels', $this->getWriterPart('Rels')->writeDrawingRelationships($this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i), $chartRef1, $this->includeCharts));

                    // Drawings
                    $zip->addFromString('xl/drawings/drawing' . ($i + 1) . '.xml', $this->getWriterPart('Drawing')->writeDrawings($this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i), $this->includeCharts));
                } elseif (isset($unparsedLoadedData['sheets'][$sheetCodeName]['drawingAlternateContents'])) {
                    // Drawings
                    $zip->addFromString('xl/drawings/drawing' . ($i + 1) . '.xml', $this->getWriterPart('Drawing')->writeDrawings($this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i), $this->includeCharts));
                }

                // Add comment relationship parts
                if (count($this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i)->getComments()) > 0) {
                    // VML Comments
                    $zip->addFromString('xl/drawings/vmlDrawing' . ($i + 1) . '.vml', $this->getWriterPart('Comments')->writeVMLComments($this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i)));

                    // Comments
                    $zip->addFromString('xl/comments' . ($i + 1) . '.xml', $this->getWriterPart('Comments')->writeComments($this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i)));
                }

                // Add unparsed relationship parts
                if (isset($unparsedLoadedData['sheets'][$this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i)->getCodeName()]['vmlDrawings'])) {
                    foreach ($unparsedLoadedData['sheets'][$this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i)->getCodeName()]['vmlDrawings'] as $vmlDrawing) {
                        $zip->addFromString($vmlDrawing['filePath'], $vmlDrawing['content']);
                    }
                }

                // Add header/footer relationship parts
                if (count($this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i)->getHeaderFooter()->getImages()) > 0) {
                    // VML Drawings
                    $zip->addFromString('xl/drawings/vmlDrawingHF' . ($i + 1) . '.vml', $this->getWriterPart('Drawing')->writeVMLHeaderFooterImages($this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i)));

                    // VML Drawing relationships
                    $zip->addFromString('xl/drawings/_rels/vmlDrawingHF' . ($i + 1) . '.vml.rels', $this->getWriterPart('Rels')->writeHeaderFooterDrawingRelationships($this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i)));

                    // Media
                    foreach ($this->spreadSheet->getSheet($i)->getHeaderFooter()->getImages() as $image) {
                        $zip->addFromString('xl/media/' . $image->getIndexedFilename(), file_get_contents($image->getPath()));
                    }
                }
            }

            // Add media
            for ($i = 0; $i < $this->getDrawingHashTable()->count(); ++$i) {
                if ($this->getDrawingHashTable()->getByIndex($i) instanceof WorksheetDrawing) {
                    $imageContents = null;
                    $imagePath = $this->getDrawingHashTable()->getByIndex($i)->getPath();
                    if (strpos($imagePath, 'zip://') !== false) {
                        $imagePath = substr($imagePath, 6);
                        $imagePathSplitted = explode('#', $imagePath);

                        $imageZip = new ZipArchive();
                        $imageZip->open($imagePathSplitted[0]);
                        $imageContents = $imageZip->getFromName($imagePathSplitted[1]);
                        $imageZip->close();
                        unset($imageZip);
                    } else {
                        $imageContents = file_get_contents($imagePath);
                    }

                    $zip->addFromString('xl/media/' . str_replace(' ', '_', $this->getDrawingHashTable()->getByIndex($i)->getIndexedFilename()), $imageContents);
                } elseif ($this->getDrawingHashTable()->getByIndex($i) instanceof MemoryDrawing) {
                    ob_start();
                    call_user_func(
                        $this->getDrawingHashTable()->getByIndex($i)->getRenderingFunction(),
                        $this->getDrawingHashTable()->getByIndex($i)->getImageResource()
                    );
                    $imageContents = ob_get_contents();
                    ob_end_clean();

                    $zip->addFromString('xl/media/' . str_replace(' ', '_', $this->getDrawingHashTable()->getByIndex($i)->getIndexedFilename()), $imageContents);
                }
            }

            Functions::setReturnDateType($saveDateReturnType);
            Calculation::getInstance($this->spreadSheet)->getDebugLog()->setWriteDebugLog($saveDebugLog);

            // Close file
            if ($zip->close() === false) {
                throw new WriterException("Could not close zip file $pFilename.");
            }

            // If a temporary file was used, copy it to the correct file stream
            if ($originalFilename != $pFilename) {

                $tmpFile = $pFilename;

                if (copy($pFilename, $originalFilename) === false) {
                    throw new WriterException("Could not copy temporary zip file $pFilename to $originalFilename.");
                }
                @unlink($pFilename);
            }
        } else {
            throw new WriterException('PhpSpreadsheet object unassigned.');
        }
    }
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFTER MANY HOURS OF SEARCHING I FOUND THE SOLUTION TO THIS!

For any of you that need this... I resolved my problem like this:

```php
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');

// Create a temporary file of and write our data to it
$excel_file_tmp = tempnam("/tmp", 'tmp');
$writer->save($excel_file_tmp);

// Now zip the file and move the temporary file to it
$zip_file_tmp = tempnam("/tmp", 'tmp');
$zip = new ZipArchive();

$zip->open($zip_file_tmp, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
$zip->addFile($excel_file_tmp, $job_id.'-space_capture_data.xlsx');
$zip->close();
```

Thanks to Arkadiusz G. who provided the answer: [PHPExcel download as zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059912/phpexcel-download-as-zip-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in memory instead of writing to the disk:

```php
// write spreadsheet to memory
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$fp = fopen('php://memory', 'rwb');
$writer->save($fp);
rewind($fp);
$content = '';
while (!feof($fp)) {
        $content .= fread($fp, 8000);
}
fclose($fp);
    
// write memory to zip
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$localname = iconv('utf-8', 'IBM437', 'myName');
$zip->addFromString($localname, $content);
```